# Is there any particular difference between strval and casting to string like (string) $var

Tags: php, string, types, casting

It seems to be that there is no difference between the 2 methods since `var_dump` returns the same result using both methods.

*Simple Example:*

```
// integer 
$var = 3;
```

*Methods and Outputs:*

```
var_dump($var);         // ouput: int(3)
var_dump((string) $var);  // string(1) "3"
var_dump(strval($var));  // string(1) "3"
```

As you see case 2 and 3 returns a string as excepted.

What do you think?

Comment: strval() is a function and (string) is typecasting operation. That is the only difference.

Comment: Actually theres also speed. (string) is about twice faster than strval()
source : http://leifw.wickland.net/2009/08/performance-of-converting-integer-to.html

Comment: For all future visitors: http://web.archive.org/web/20150302015725/http://leifw.wickland.net/2009/08/performance-of-converting-integer-to.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest difference will be the fact that a function (any function) incurs some overhead. It's a negligible amount so, for the most part, this discussion is more academic than anything else. Gerton's link proves it's slower on point but you're unlikely to notice that gap in normal execution because he ran that function **1 million times** to get a **0.7s gap** (and he was using PHP 5.2, while PHP 7 might make that gap even smaller).  [Consider this article on function execution time](http://jpauli.github.io/2015/01/22/on-php-function-calls.html)

> The second tip is that PHP is fast, believe me. For what you ask it to do, the way it does the job and the tools it represents to you : it is fast, efficient, reliable. There is not that much room to optimize PHP scripts, at least not as if you were using lower level language like C. The main trick is to optimize what is repeated : loops. If you use a profiler showing you the hot path of you script, you'll happen to find that it is likely to be located into loops. That's the same when we, as contributors, optimize PHP itself : we won't bother optimizing a part of code a few users will trigger, but better optimize the hot path : variable accesses, engine function calls, etc... Because in here, the very little micro-second earned will translate to final milli-seconds or even seconds, as such code is run tons of times (usually involving in loops). Except foreach(), in PHP, loops are the same and lead to the same OPCode. Turning a PHP's while loop into a for loop is both useless and silly. Once more : profiling will tell you that.